# Created a runner in Protractor but it errors out after passing the first test?

Tags: automation, protractor

**This is my Spec:**

```
import {DotComPage} from "../../../pages/web/dotComPage";
import {browser, element, by, $, $$, ProtractorExpectedConditions, ElementFinder, protractor, } from "protractor";
import {HkZhMarket} from "./HkZhMarket.e2e-spec";
import {AuZhMarket} from "./AuZhMarket.e2e-spec";

export function AuEnMarket() {
    describe("Australia English", () => {
        const dotComPage = new DotComPage();
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
        it('Clicks on the market Australia and language English', async () => {
            dotComPage.get();
            browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dotComPage.firstTimeVisitorButton))
            dotComPage.firstTimeVisitorButton.click();
            browser.waitForAngular();
            browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.optanon-alert-box-wrapper[style="bottom: 0px;"]')), 5000);
            browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(dotComPage.acceptCookiesButton), 5000);
            dotComPage.acceptCookiesButton.click();
            dotComPage.usFlagButton.click();
            browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dotComPage.auMarketButton), 5000)
            dotComPage.auMarketButton.click();
            dotComPage.auFlagButtonEnglish.click();
            browser.wait(EC.urlContains('enu-AU'));
            });
        });
}
```

This is the test runner that I created which pulls the function that I wrapped around my test:

```
import {AuEnMarket} from "..//FlagMarketLanguage/AuEnMarket.e2e-spec";
import {AuZhMarket} from "../FlagMarketLanguage/AuZhMarket.e2e-spec";


describe ('FlagMarketLanguageTests',  async ()=> {
        AuEnMarket()
        AuZhMarket()

})
```

When I run the FlagMarketlanguageTests the first test always passes but the browser does not close.  The 2nd tests (and I have more that I didn't post) always fails.  Errors that I get are:

Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

and

A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

or

Failed: invalid session id

Answer (score 0):

Just write your spec in the export file. Don't have to export in a method format.

```
import {DotComPage} from "../../../pages/web/dotComPage";
import {browser, element, by, $, $$, ProtractorExpectedConditions, ElementFinder, protractor, } from "protractor";
import {HkZhMarket} from "./HkZhMarket.e2e-spec";
import {AuZhMarket} from "./AuZhMarket.e2e-spec";


    describe("Australia English", () => {
        const dotComPage = new DotComPage();
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
        it('Clicks on the market Australia and language English', async () => {
            dotComPage.get();
            browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dotComPage.firstTimeVisitorButton))
            dotComPage.firstTimeVisitorButton.click();
            browser.waitForAngular();
            browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.optanon-alert-box-wrapper[style="bottom: 0px;"]')), 5000);
            browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(dotComPage.acceptCookiesButton), 5000);
            dotComPage.acceptCookiesButton.click();
            dotComPage.usFlagButton.click();
            browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dotComPage.auMarketButton), 5000)
            dotComPage.auMarketButton.click();
            dotComPage.auFlagButtonEnglish.click();
            browser.wait(EC.urlContains('enu-AU'));
            });
        });
```

In the main specs just require the file and delete it from cache before loading it for second time.

```
describe ('FlagMarketLanguageTests',  async ()=> {
      require('../FlagMarketLanguage/AuZhMarket.e2e-spec');
      let resolved = require.resolve('../FlagMarketLanguage/AuZhMarket.e2e-spec');
      delete require.cache[resolved];
      require('../FlagMarketLanguage/AuZhMarket.e2e-spec');
})
```

Comment: Not sure that is exactly what I'm looking for, but we did figure out that by adding the following 2 lines spec1 will move on to spec2 and run it.  Kind of a weird round about way, but when I ran the first test it completed and switched back to the home page but it would never run the next spec.  This works though unless you have a better idea?

browser.manage().deleteAllCookies()
browser.get("https://www.google.com/")